# htaccess rewrite rule explanation

Tags: apache, .htaccess, lamp

I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Can someone succcinctly tell me what this actually does, or where I can find the list of variables?

Answer (score 3):

In short this forward every request to `index.php` in current directory if request is not for a valid file, directory or link. It will pass URL in a query parameter `url` to `index.php`

So effectively a URO of `/foobar` gets forwarded (internally) to `/index.php?url=foobar`

Flags used are:

- L   - Last (inject rule again)
- QSA - Query String Append

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)